# WP Cli - post add meta in xargs after wp post generate - add multiple fields

Tags: custom-field, wp-cli, automation

This command will generate posts and create a field with key "bar" and value "foo"

```
wp post generate --format=ids --count=10 | xargs -d ' ' -I % wp post meta add % foo bar
```

This does not seem to work:

```
wp post generate --format=ids --count=10 | xargs -d ' ' -I % wp post meta add % foo bar ; wp post meta add % key_2 value_2
```

How could create 2 meta fields and values after the wp post generate command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the syntax of `xargs` to run multiple commands using the same placeholder:

`wp post generate --format=ids --count=10 | sed -e "s/ /\n/g" | xargs -n1 -I % sh -c 'echo "Adding fields for %"; wp post meta add % foo bar; wp post meta add % key_2 value_2';`

**Update**:

The output of `wp post generate` is post ids with spaces for the delimiter. I'm sure there is a better way for xargs to process spaces but I'm using `sed` to replace the spaces with newlines.

Reference:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/431167/sed-replace-all-tabs-and-spaces-with-a-single-space
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/959024/what-is-the-difference-between-find-with-exec-and-xargs/959231
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958957

Comment: I get: Error: Too many positional arguments: 2467 2468 2469 2470 2471 2472 2473 foo bar
Error: Too many positional arguments: 2467 2468 2469 2470 2471 2472 2473 key_2 value_2

Comment: @BenB - Updated the code above to mutate the data in the pipe before it hits xargs.

Comment: Works like a charm!